# Custom form and DropZoneJS

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I tried to search to get my upload function with dropzone to work with my own custom form. Unfortunately other threads here on stackoverflow and other side haven't helped me so much. So perhaps anyone can go to the real basics and help me understand this.

My problem is to get information from input fields when I push the submit button. The image does upload and get to the folder as it should, but I wan't the information from input field also, so I can push that information to the database later. Currently I just tried to get the information from the input field and write it out in PHP, but I don't get any information to the variable. Can anyone help me understand this?

Here is my code:

HTML and JavaScript code

```
<!-- Innholdet på siden -->
<h1 class="page-header">Last opp bilder</h1>

<pre>
    <form action="" method="post" class="dropzone" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Drag and drop felt med knapp som henter opp uforsker -->
        <h4>Slipp bildene her eller <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button dz-clickable"/> trykk her for å velge bilder!</h4>
        <input type="text" id="photographer" name="photographer">
    </form>
</pre>

<div class="table table-striped files" id="previews">
    <div id="template" class="file-row" style="border: solid 1px #CCCCCC; position: relative; top: 10px; padding: 10px; background-color: #f9f9f9">
        <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
        <!--Div-tag som styler hele thumbnail-preview visningen-->
        <span class="preview" style="float: left;"><img data-dz-thumbnail/></span>
        <!--div-tag som styler 'name' til filen som lastes opp-->
        <p class="name" style="float: left; margin: 10px 50px 0 50px;" data-dz-name></p>
        <!-- Henter ut filstørrelsen på bilde -->
        <p class="size" style="float: left; margin-top: 10px;" data-dz-size></p>
        <!--Knapp som sletter enkeltbilde i køen-->
        <button style="margin: 10px 0 0 70px;" data-dz-remove id="cancel2" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
            Cancel
        </button>
        <br>
        <!-- Selve progressbaren-->
        <div class="progress" style="float: left; margin-left: 50px; width: 20%;">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" id="test" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
        </div>
        <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
        <br style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="actions" class="row">
    <!-- Knappene -->
    <!-- Legg til filer -->
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button dz-clickable"/>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Legg til filer</span>
    </span>
    <!-- Denne knappen starter selve opplastningsfunksjonen-->
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="upload" class="btn btn-primary start">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
        Last opp
    </button>

    <!-- Denne knappen fjerner elementer i køen-->
    <button data-dz-remove id="cancel" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
        Cancel
    </button>
</div>

<script>
    // Deklarerer variabel som plukker opp div-taggen template som skal brukes i visning av opplastende filer
    var previewNode = document.querySelector("div#template");
    previewNode.id = "";

    // Ting som jeg ikke helt forstår
    var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
    previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

    //Sørger for at ikke queue'n blir kjørt automatisk før 'go'-knappen er trykket
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    //Sperre som gjør at opplastningsfunksjonen kun tar imot bilder og ikke dokumenter.. Btw .svg filer fungerer også
    var acceptedFileTypes = "image/*";

    //Deklarerer selve dropzonen og definerer noen variabler fra bibiloteket til dropzone
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
        url: 'inc/uploads.php',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        paramName: 'file',
        maxFiles:10,
        previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
        previewsContainer: "#previews",
        headers: {"MyAppname-Service-Type": "Dropzone"},
        acceptedFiles: acceptedFileTypes,
        clickable:".fileinput-button"
    });

    //Registrerer knappentrykk og kjører kode
    $('#upload').click(function () {
        //Prosesserer køen
        myDropzone.processQueue();
        //'Success'-event som kan høres på og kjøres kode etter alle filer er akseptert
        myDropzone.on("success", function(file,responseText){
            console.log(file);
            var test = document.getElementById('erik');
            var ok = document.getElementById('ok');
            test.innerHTML = ok.value;
            var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
            txt.innerHTML = responseText;
            removeContentDelay();
        });
    });

    //Avbyrt-knapp som sletter hele køen
    $('#cancel').click(function () {
        myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
    });

    // Funksjon som setter en forsinkelse på hendelsen removeAllFiles
    function removeContentDelay() {
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(removeAllFilesAfterDelay,2000);
    }
    // Fuksjon som tømmer køen etter perdefinert tid i funksjonen removeContentDelay
    function removeAllFilesAfterDelay(responseText){
        myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
    }
</script>
```

#PHP - code

```
<?php

$test = $_REQUEST["photographer"];
echo "<h1>$test</h1>";

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n HEEEI";
} else {
    echo "Possible file uploads attack!\n";
}

echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the "sending" event in dropzone. This is a bit of code from an application I have where I am doing this:

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
   var titleVal = file.previewElement.querySelector(".title input").value;
   formData.append("Title", titleVal);
}
```

Comment: And then you can use php as usual to get the value in the php file?

Comment: After some try and fail, It finally works! Thank u so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work with this code on the PHP-side:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    echo "RECEIVED ON SERVER: \n";
    echo "FILES: \n";

    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "\$_POST: fra php filen \n";
    print_r($_POST);
}


$photographer = ($_POST['photographer']);
```